# Flutter Tar : Failed to set default locale in android studio IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I'm using android sutdio and fultter in ios. For Application.

I want to generate build for iphone. but it gives me an error

> Tar : Failed to set default locale

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to delete the `bin/cache/` directory inside the Flutter install directory and run `flutter doctor` and then try again?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Thanks, its working.

Answer (score 7):

Delete the `bin/cache/` directory inside the Flutter install directory 
and run `flutter doctor` and then try again.